# Streaming video via ffmpeg and NGINX works approximately 80% of the time

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, nginx

On **Server 1** I am running this (and it's looping):

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i game.webm -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://1.1.1.1/live
```

On **Server 2** I have NGINX setup and I am running this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://localhost/live -c copy -f flv game-SPOOL.mp4 -c copy -f flv - | ffplay -f flv -
```

Since the command on Server 1 is in a loop, I just keep running and stopping the command on Server 2.

What is strange, it it streams both video and audio successfully about 80% of the time, but 20% of the time only the audio gets through.

Out of all the ffmpeg output text, I've included some of what I believe is the most important information. As you can see, when it fails, it literally doesn't pick up the video stream  (Stream #0:1).

Output on Server 2 when it works (ffplay outputs video and audio)

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/live': sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1920
    displayHeight   : 1080
    fps             : 30
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 5685.882000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s 
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5999 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
```

Output on Server 2 when it does not work (ffplay outputs video and audio)

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/live': sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1920
    displayHeight   : 1080
    fps             : 30
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 5309.446000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Add wait_video to the config.

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#wait_video

You should also probably set a smaller GOP size on the broadcast side.